# how to fetch a value from build.properties to persistence.xml?

Tags: java, hibernate, build, persistence.xml

In our project I need to fetch some values from build.properties to persistence.xml. Please let me know if there is any possible way?

Answer (score 0):

For example: build.properties contains

```
 username = root
 password = shoot
```

as properties then you could change the persistence.xml to have values like

```
 <username>@username@</username>
 <password value="@password@"/>
```

then your build.xml should be something like this will work.

```
<target name="replace">
    <property file="build.properties"/>
    <replace file="persistence.xml" token="@username@" value="${username}"/>
    <replace file="persistence.xml" token="@password@" value="${password}"/>
</target>
```

Here $username and $password values are automatically identified by ant from the `<property>` tag and you could access values with key as a name.

Comment: how could I inject values of the build.properties to persistence.xml? These link are not showing persistence.xml. I need to get the values into persistence.xml from build.properties while the build.xml is running....that means values should reflex in persistence.xml automatically...

Comment: Please go through the Replace values with Ant Task link for doing that.

Comment: Sorry..I didn't get any idea from this link. What this <replace> tag actually do?

Comment: for example you have a value which needs to be replaced at build time?
<bean-name>@name@</bean-name>. And if you define name=X bean in build.properties file. Then replace tag will replace @name@ with X at the time of build.

Comment: Actually in my code, build.proerties contains username=uname, password=pwd. I need to get automatically reflected this values under <properties> tag in persistence.xml(like <properties><property name="hibernate.connection.username" value=uname /><property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=pwd /> while build.xml is running...what all tags I need to write in build.xml. urgent requirement..please help..

Comment: This is the 100% worst answer as generally the persistence.xml is in the jar file and on a QA or production server, you modify the build.properties on that machine and QA can't modify the persistence.xml file because it is in the jar file and QA should not have ant.

Comment: FYI, this is run on a build system which modifies the configuration of the application based on the build type(QA/PROD) then the configured WAR/EAR moved to respective environment. And one more thing, in question it's not mentioned on QA/PROD.

Answer (score 0):

I had to just recall that myself.  The correct way of doing that is such

```
    Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
    props.put("hibernate.connection.username", "sa");
    props.put("hibernate.connection.password", "");
    props.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:h2:mem:test_mem;MVCC=true");
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("inmemory", props);
```

You can instead of hardcoding username like I did temporarily there read it from your build.properties file.  Have fun.

Dean